# How can I upload data from Java Cloud Function to SQL table?

Tags: java, sql, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to upload a JSON to a cloud bucket to trigger one cloud function to upload the JSON's data to a SQL table. I would like to know how to upload bucket data with an INSERT INTO query once GCSEvent is triggered.

```
package com.example;

import com.example.Example.GCSEvent;
import com.google.cloud.functions.BackgroundFunction;
import com.google.cloud.functions.Context;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Example implements BackgroundFunction<GCSEvent> {
  private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Example.class.getName());

  @Override
  public void accept(GCSEvent event, Context context) {
    logger.info("Processing file: " + event.name);
    HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
    config.setJdbcUrl(String.format("jdbc:mysql:///%s", "***"));
    config.setUsername("root");
    config.setPassword("");
    config.addDataSourceProperty("socketFactory", "com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory");
    config.addDataSourceProperty("cloudSqlInstance", "***");
  }

  public static class GCSEvent {
    String bucket;
    String name;
    String metageneration;
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay, well you've got part of the code there... where are you stuck?

Comment: Sorry, it´s my first time asking in stack overflow. I want to get the data from the JSON I upload in the bucket. How can I do it with that public static class GCSEvent {]???

Comment: Okay, if the problem isn't actually related to the SQL insertion, I suggest you take that part out of the question. There's sample code in https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage#functions-calling-storage-java that logs the bucket, object name etc in response to a Storage trigger.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much :)

Comment: download the file, read the file, parse the JSON, build your query, run your query on the database. It's the main steps that you have to implement.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.